# Overlaying multiple rasters covering the same area with a single band

Tags: qgis, raster, arcmap, layers, esri-ascii-raster

I have a data set that contains rainfall values for every 5 mins of a day in different rasters (each raster has rainfall for 5 minutes - ie 12*24 = 288 rasters per day). I want to overlay all the rasters together to get the rainfall for the entire day in *one raster*. all the rasters cover the same area (the UK). what is the best tool to do this? I have access to both QGIS and ARCGIS, but not sure if mosaicking all the rasters per day will give me the total rainfall, or if I should merge. What is the best way to get the total rainfall per day in raster format? Basically what I want is a functionality that will allow me to overlay all the rasters and sum the values for each overlapping point.

Comment: @user2856 Thank you for helping! Does that create a new raster with the total rainfall for each cell or merely displays the information? I need the totals to be in a new raster so that I can then extract the rainfall by constituency.

Answer (score 1):

You  an use the ArcGIS [Cell Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) tool (requires Spatial Analyst extension) with the SUM statistic (or MAX if your 5min values are cumulative) to output a raster of the totals.